# QuickPager Javascript works for one click, but not second click

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagination

Javascript noob here.

I've modified the plugin available online to update the menu to only show 10 entries -5/+5 of the current selected. It actually works for the first click, then stops working past there (clicking on the a href's do nothing past the first one).

Could anyone help point me in the direction to where I screwed this up?

I know this is a way to do pagination, maybe not best practice, but it's the easiest for the application I'm using and my knowledge of Javascript (none).

```
/*-------------------------------------------------
    Quick Pager jquery plugin

    Copyright (C) 2011 by Dan Drayne

    Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
    of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
    in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
    to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
    copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
    furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:

    The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in
    all copies or substantial portions of the Software.

    THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
    IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
    FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
    AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
    LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
    OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN
    THE SOFTWARE.

    v1.1/   18/09/09 * bug fix by John V - http://blog.geekyjohn.com/
-------------------------------------------------*/

(function($) {

  $.fn.quickPager = function(options) {

    var defaults = {
      pageSize: 10,
      currentPage: 1,
      holder: null,
      pagerLocation: "both"
    };

    var options = $.extend(defaults, options);


    return this.each(function() {


      var selector = $(this);
      var pageCounter = 1;

      selector.wrap("<div class='PaginationContainer'></div>");

      selector.children().each(function(i){

        if(i < pageCounter*options.pageSize && i >= (pageCounter-1)*options.pageSize) {
        $(this).addClass("PaginationPage"+pageCounter);
        }
        else {
          $(this).addClass("PaginationPage"+(pageCounter+1));
          pageCounter ++;
        }

      });

      // show/hide the appropriate regions
      selector.children().hide();
      selector.children(".PaginationPage"+options.currentPage).show();

      if(pageCounter <= 1) {
        return;
      }

      //Build pager navigation
      var pageNav = "<ul class='pagination'>";
      for (i=1;i<=pageCounter;i++){
        if (i==options.currentPage) {
          pageNav += "<li class='active PaginationNav"+i+"'><a rel='"+i+"' href='#'>"+i+"</a></li>";
        }
        else{
          if(i<=10){
            pageNav += "<li class='PaginationNav"+i+"'><a rel='"+i+"' href='#'>"+i+"</a></li>";
          }
        }
      }
      pageNav += "</ul>";

      if(!options.holder) {
        switch(options.pagerLocation)
        {
        case "before":
          selector.before(pageNav);
        break;
        case "both":
          selector.before(pageNav);
          selector.after(pageNav);
        break;
        default:
          selector.after(pageNav);
        }
      }
      else {
        $(options.holder).append(pageNav);
      }

      //pager navigation behaviour
      selector.parent().find(".pagination a").click(function() {

        //grab the REL attribute
        var clickedLink = $(this).attr("rel");
        options.currentPage = clickedLink;

                //Rebuild Pager Nav
        $('.pagination').remove();
        var pageNav = "<ul class='pagination'>";
        for (i=parseInt(options.currentPage)-5;i<=pageCounter;i++){
          if (i==options.currentPage) {
            pageNav += "<li class='active PaginationNav"+i+"'><a rel='"+i+"' href='#'>"+i+"</a></li>";
          }
          else{
            if(i<=parseInt(options.currentPage)+5){
              pageNav += "<li class='PaginationNav"+i+"'><a rel='"+i+"' href='#'>"+i+"</a></li>";
            }
          }
        }
        pageNav += "</ul>";

        if(!options.holder) {
          switch(options.pagerLocation)
          {
          case "before":
            selector.before(pageNav);
          break;
          case "both":
            selector.before(pageNav);
            selector.after(pageNav);
          break;
          default:
            selector.after(pageNav);
          }
        }
        else {
          $(options.holder).append(pageNav);
        }


        if(options.holder) {
          $(this).parent("li").parent("ul").parent(options.holder).find("li.currentPage").removeClass("active");
          $(this).parent("li").parent("ul").parent(options.holder).find("a[rel='"+clickedLink+"']").parent("li").addClass("active");
        }
        else {
          //remove current current (!) page
          $(this).parent("li").parent("ul").parent(".PaginationContainer").find("li.active").removeClass("active");
          //Add current page highlighting
          $(this).parent("li").parent("ul").parent(".PaginationContainer").find("a[rel='"+clickedLink+"']").parent("li").addClass("active");
        }


        //hide and show relevant links
        selector.children().hide();
        selector.find(".PaginationPage"+clickedLink).show();

        return false;
      });
    });
  }


})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Clicking on the link does acctually bring you to the top of the page, so the a href is working. just not entering `selector.parent().find(".pagination a").click(function()` again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered this with changing `.click` to `on('click'` while referencing a static parent object.

### Changed

```
 selector.parent().find(".pagination a").click(function()
```

### To:

```
 $('#PaginationContainer').on('click', '.testClass', function(e) {
```

## Full Code, feel free to use and modify.

```
/*-------------------------------------------------
    Quick Pager jquery plugin

    Copyright (C) 2011 by Dan Drayne

    Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
    of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
    in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
    to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
    copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
    furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:

    The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in
    all copies or substantial portions of the Software.

    THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
    IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
    FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
    AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
    LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
    OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN
    THE SOFTWARE.

    v1.1/   18/09/09 * bug fix by John V - http://blog.geekyjohn.com/
-------------------------------------------------*/

(function($) {

  $.fn.quickPager = function(options) {

    var defaults = {
      pageSize: 10,
      currentPage: 1,
      holder: null,
      pagerLocation: "both"
    };

    var options = $.extend(defaults, options);


    return this.each(function() {


      var selector = $(this);
      var pageCounter = 1;

      selector.wrap("<div class='PaginationContainer' id='PaginationContainer'></div>");

      selector.children().each(function(i){

        if(i < pageCounter*options.pageSize && i >= (pageCounter-1)*options.pageSize) {
        $(this).addClass("PaginationPage"+pageCounter);
        }
        else {
          $(this).addClass("PaginationPage"+(pageCounter+1));
          pageCounter ++;
        }

      });

      // show/hide the appropriate regions
      selector.children().hide();
      selector.children(".PaginationPage"+options.currentPage).show();

      if(pageCounter <= 1) {
        return;
      }

      //Build pager navigation
      var pageNav = "<ul class='pagination'>";
      for (i=1;i<=pageCounter;i++){
        if (i==options.currentPage) {
          pageNav += "<li class='active PaginationNav"+i+"'><a rel='"+i+"' href='#' class='testClass'>"+i+"</a></li>";
        }
        else{
          if(i<=10){
            pageNav += "<li class='PaginationNav"+i+"'><a rel='"+i+"' href='#' class='testClass'>"+i+"</a></li>";
          }
        }
      }
      pageNav += "</ul>";

      if(!options.holder) {
        switch(options.pagerLocation)
        {
        case "before":
          selector.before(pageNav);
        break;
        case "both":
          selector.before(pageNav);
          selector.after(pageNav);
        break;
        default:
          selector.after(pageNav);
        }
      }
      else {
        $(options.holder).append(pageNav);
      }

      //pager navigation behaviour
      $('#PaginationContainer').on('click', '.testClass', function(e) {

        //grab the REL attribute
        var clickedLink = $(this).attr("rel");
        options.currentPage = clickedLink;

                //Rebuild Pager Nav
        $('.pagination').remove();
        var pageNav = "<ul class='pagination'>";
        var i2 = 1;
        if(pageCounter<=10){
          i = 0;
        }else{
          i = parseInt(options.currentPage)-5;
        }
        while (i<=pageCounter){
          if(options.currentPage>=6&&pageCounter>10){
            if (i==options.currentPage) {
                pageNav += "<li class='active PaginationNav"+i+"'><a rel='"+i+"' href='#' class='testClass'>"+i+"</a></li>";
              }
              else{
                if(i<=parseInt(options.currentPage)+4){
                  pageNav += "<li class='PaginationNav"+i+"'><a rel='"+i+"' href='#' class='testClass'>"+i+"</a></li>";
                }
              }
            }
            else
            {
              if(pageCounter<=10){
                if (i==options.currentPage) {
                  pageNav += "<li class='active PaginationNav"+i+"'><a rel='"+i+"' href='#' class='testClass'>"+i+"</a></li>";
                }
                else{
                  if(i>=1){
                    pageNav += "<li class='PaginationNav"+i+"'><a rel='"+i+"' href='#' class='testClass'>" +i+"</a></li>";
                  }
                }
              }else{
                if (i2==options.currentPage) {
                  pageNav += "<li class='active PaginationNav"+i2+"'><a rel='"+i2+"' href='#' class='testClass'>"+i2+"</a></li>";
                }
                else{
                  if(i2<=10){
                    pageNav += "<li class='PaginationNav"+i2+"'><a rel='"+i2+"' href='#' class='testClass'>"+i2+"</a></li>";
                  }
                }
                i2++;
              }
            }
            i++;
            }
        pageNav += "</ul>";

        if(!options.holder) {
          switch(options.pagerLocation)
          {
          case "before":
            selector.before(pageNav);
          break;
          case "both":
            selector.before(pageNav);
            selector.after(pageNav);
          break;
          default:
            selector.after(pageNav);
          }
        }
        else {
          $(options.holder).append(pageNav);
        }


        if(options.holder) {
          $(this).parent("li").parent("ul").parent(options.holder).find("li.currentPage").removeClass("active");
          $(this).parent("li").parent("ul").parent(options.holder).find("a[rel='"+clickedLink+"']").parent("li").addClass("active");
        }
        else {
          //remove current current (!) page
          $(this).parent("li").parent("ul").parent(".PaginationContainer").find("li.active").removeClass("active");
          //Add current page highlighting
          $(this).parent("li").parent("ul").parent(".PaginationContainer").find("a[rel='"+clickedLink+"']").parent("li").addClass("active");
        }


        //hide and show relevant links
        selector.children().hide();
        selector.find(".PaginationPage"+clickedLink).show();

        return false;
      });
    });
  }


})(jQuery);
```